# Why am I getting ClassCastException in Jenkins build

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson

I am new to Jenkins. I am getting the following error. Please help

```
FATAL: hudson.scm.SCMRevisionState$None cannot be cast to hudson.scm.SVNRevisionState
java.lang.ClassCastException: hudson.scm.SCMRevisionState$None cannot be cast to hudson.scm.SVNRevisionState
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.calcChangeLog(SubversionSCM.java:730)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:865)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:496)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
```

Comment: What is leading to the error? Give some context please

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I was trying to build a project through Jenkins, It is resolved now. The error came because the project was getting updated at the same time in the repository

Answer (score 0):

install svn plugin  if you are trying to checkout SVN Repo